# Kernel died if successive conv layers on Keras

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using the following convolutional network using Keras.

```
    def CNN_model():
        # Create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), input_shape=(1, 256, 256), activation='elu'))
        model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10, 10)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='elu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(16, activation='elu'))
        model.add(Dense(nb_models, activation='softmax'))
        # Compile model
        my_adam_optimizer = Adam(lr=initial_learning_rate, decay=decay_rate)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=my_adam_optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

I don't understand why the kernel stops each time I am trying to train my model. If you just remove the second convolutional layer (remove `model.add(Conv2D(10, (3, 3), activation='elu'))`), then the model fits.

Does anyone know why it is impossible to me to put two convolutional layers in a row ?

Comment: Are you sure your keras is configured for "channels_first"? The default is "channels_last" (256,256,1)

Comment: Keras recognizes the data_format parameter automatically.
I found the problem. This was due to my CPU memory that explodes with the same batch size, when I use successive convolutionnal layers.

Comment: Does it? That's new.